# How to create breathing wall effect?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to recreate the effect of the one in this video: [Breathing walls](http://vimeo.com/21240204)

[image]

This is my first time manipulating images, and because of that, I don't even have a clue where to start.

But I think the way to do this must be transforming the geometry of the image with sine waves, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Take a look at `ImageTransformation`;

Comment: The author of those videos wrote about it on his blog, although not with the details required to implement the thing it has a good source that might help someone: [here](http://countyourculture.com/2011/03/13/form-constants-visual-cortex/).

Comment: The link should be this: [countyourculture.com/2011/03/19/breathing-wall-visualization](http://countyourculture.com/2011/03/19/breathing-wall-visualization/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way of implementing sinusoidal undulations, updated to write out an animated gif, and to use a smaller image, as suggested by Murta.

```
img = ImageTake[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMwRi.jpg"], {200, 500}, {200, 600}];
Export["breathing.gif", 
 Table[ImageTransformation[img, # + {.004 Sin[4 #[[1]] + p], .005 Sin[5 #[[1]] + p]} &, 
   Padding -> Black], {p, 0, 2 Pi, 0.3}], "DisplayDurations" -> 0.3]
```

You can make the animation smoother by replacing 0.3 with 0.1 or smaller and the DisplayDurations 0.3 to 0.1.

Comment: Cool.. With ImageResize the effect get more fluid: `img = ImageResize[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/XMwRi.jpg"], 400]`

Answer (score 13):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pgul.gif"];
image = img[[3]];

gr = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[.1], Black]],
FaceForm[Opacity[0]], Rectangle[{0.1, 0.1}, {.9, .9}]}, ImageSize -> 400];

Animate[
   Overlay[{
            ParametricPlot3D[{x , y , 1 + .2 ( Cos[ t y + (1 - t) x] )}, 
             {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
             Mesh -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Boxed -> False, 
             Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400, 
             Lighting-> "Neutral", (*thanks: Olexandr R. *)
             PlotStyle -> Texture[image], ViewPoint -> Top], gr}, 
      Alignment -> Center], 
 {t, 0, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> .5]
```

[image]

Comment: Needs `Lighting -> "Neutral"`. Otherwise it's the breathing, oddly pinkish, color changing wall. But a definite +1 for a simple and effective approach to producing the undulations.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thank you - excellent point.